# How to get substring from a sql table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pattern-matching

So I have a column (called account_uri) in a postgres table that looks like this:

```
/randomCharacters/123456/randomNumbers
```

I need to query for the substring in the middle, which is a string of characters between two `/` symbols.

My current attempt looked like this:

```
SELECT 
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri))))
FROM exp_logs
LIMIT 15
```

Which selects only the randomNumbers and not the desired numbers.

I tried to build on that idea though and used

```
(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))),1,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([account_uri]),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(account_uri)))))))
```

but that only returns a bunch of `/` symbols and no numbers at all.

If anyone can help me query for this substring, I would be immensely grateful

Comment: are you sure that the question is for `postgresql`? cause there is no `charindex()` function per postgres documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  split_part(account_url, '/', 3)
from exp_logs;
```

works.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html

Compatibility: 8.3+

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5e931/1

Comment: shouldn't it be 2 instead of 3?

Comment: I doubt the question is for postgresql but if it's then nice answer.

Comment: @FuzzyTree it would parse the string like this: /randomCharacters/123456/randomNumbers = 1/2/3/4 , due to the leading '/'

Answer (score 3):

A couple of solutions, sorted by *fastest first*:

```
SELECT split_part(account_uri, '/', 3)        AS solution_1  -- Neil's solution
      ,substring(account_uri,'^/.*?/(.*?)/')  AS solution_2
      ,substring(account_uri,'^/[^/]*/(\d*)') AS solution_3
      ,(string_to_array(account_uri,'/'))[3]  AS solution_4
FROM (
   VALUES
     ('/randomCharacters/123456/randomNumbers')
    ,('/v o,q9063´6qu/24734782/2369872986')
    ,('/DFJTDZTJ/1/234567')
    ,('/ ijgtoqu29836UGB /999/29672')
   ) exp_logs(account_uri);
```

[@Neil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25272243/939860) proved fastest in a quick test on a table with 30k rows.