# Get substring between 2 characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the characters between a URL like so in postgreSQL:

> www.abc.com/hello/xyz
>
> www.abc.com/hi/pqr
>
> www.abc.com/yellow/xyz

I want to get

> hello
>
> hi
>
> yellow

This is what I have so far:

```
select distinct substring(url, position('/' in url)+ 1) theURL from table;
```

I am only able to get the first "/"

I am not sure how to get the position of the second one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One method uses `regexp_split_to_array()`:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(url, '/'::text))[2]
```

or better yet as @NeilMcGuigan suggests:

```
select split_part(url, '/', 2)
```

Comment: `split_part(url, '/', 2)` is generally the fastest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272196/how-to-get-substring-from-a-sql-table/25272243#25272243

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan is there anyway i can get all the characters after yellow in: www.abc.com/yellow/xyz/123/abc. So i want it to print: /xyz/123/abc

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan but there are multiple kinds of urls: like www.abc.com/hello/abc/456/989/tyu, i want it to print /abc/456/989/tyu in the case mentioned in the pervious comment  /xyz/123/abc. I am not getting that with right(url, position('/' in url))

Comment: @gordonlinoff I used your book in a course I taught a few years ago btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following your substring approach, and using the first substring result to feed a second search:

```
select distinct substring(
  substring(url, position('/' in url)+ 1)
  , 0
  , position('/' in substring(url, position('/' in url)+ 1))) AS theURL 
from table;
```

Essentially what the query does is use your original result from `substring` to launch a search for the next \ , so then it is able to keep the text between the first two \

And if having them sorted alphabetically is important, you could add an outer query:

```
SELECT theURL FROM (
select distinct substring(
  substring(url, position('/' in url)+ 1)
  , 0
  , position('/' in substring(url, position('/' in url)+ 1))) AS theURL 
from table
) AS xt
ORDER BY xt.theURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work even for inputs like `www.abc.com/hello`

```
SELECT DISTINCT (regexp_matches(url, '/([^/]+)'))[1] theURL
FROM table;
```

And also it will skip empty entries